# File Privileges

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, rhel

There is one user Lets call him B and he needs access Just to Read the File MEANS READ ACCESS and that file is own by another user A .

How can I grant access to user A's file to User B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard UNIX permissions aren't quite that granular.  You either need to,

1. put A and B in the same group[*] and limit the group permissions to read only or
2. use ACLs

For #1, if this is the only file you care about, create a group called *readerb*, put user B into it, and change the group ownership on the file (`chgrp`) to be *readerb*, and then set the group permissions to be read only (`chmod`).  To be fair, user A doesn't even need to be in the group assuming they still own the file.

To do #2 you need to make sure your distribution supports ACL's, you have the ACL utilities installed, and your filesystems are mounted with ACL support.

With that in place, you would use,

```
setfacl -m u:B:r thefile.b
```

to give user B access to `thefile.b`.

[*] technically user A and B don't need to be in the same group, you could just put user B into the group, or use a group user B is currently the only member of.

Comment: Lets follow Option 1 bcoz I have no idea about ACL right now. **So tell me what will be the affect of putting both users in same group ???**

Comment: If `MEANS READ ACCESS` is the *only* file or directory anywhere assigned to that group, then I believe the only affect of putting them in the same group will be that B has the group permissions for that file, rather than the everybody permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you can give 444 permissions to the file that the user wants to access...the command will be **chmod 444 /filename/** want to apply recursively and forcely you can try **chmod -Rf 444 /filename/**.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but couldn't he also issue a `chmod o+r <filename>`?

That is, assuming he is the user that owns the file, and wants someone who does not belong to the same groups that he belongs to read the file contents.